# How to get the liquidity of a pair in pancakeswap or uniswap?

Tags: web3js, truffle, uniswap, nethereum, pancakeswap

How can I know in pancakeswap or uniswap when a pair is created and how much liquidity is added?

At the moment what I have thought is to read the "PairCreated" logs of the Factory contract, but what I don't know is how to obtain the liquidity that was added to the pair.

[image]